# Running java from Apache/PHP "could not find main class"

Tags: java, php, apache, classpath, raspbian

I'm trying to allow apache and PHP to execute a java program that outputs to std:out, but i keep getting "Error: Could not find or load main class". This is all happening on Raspian.

I have my index.php in var/www and my java program in var/www/pathy-lang
Pathy.class is where my main() is located, and I get the error when i try to execute `java pathy-lang/Pathy` in either the terminal or using the backtick operator in my PHP file. Pathy works if I'm in the same directory as it and execute `java Pathy` on the command line.

I'd rather have pathy-lang elsewhere (preferably somewhere like /usr/local/lib), but I'll only contemplate that once i get it working one folder away.

I understand apache uses the www-data user to do things, will this complicate matters at all?

I assume this is either related to my file permissions, PATH or CLASSPATH. But having very little experience with linux, I have no idea where to begin trying to sort this. Due to the "not found" response I'm assuming this is a PATH or CLASSPATH error, but when answering could you also mention permission setting as once the PATH is set that will likely be the next hurdle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend helped me out, and told me about the -cp option on java to define the classpath. It seems as though my hunch was right as because I set the classpath in .profile it wouldn't work for any other user than me.

By defining the full classpath in the -cp option then saying what class main() was in, it worked.